# Airport kiosk signage title

Tags: copywriting, industrial-design, kiosk

I am designing signage for a Kiosk machine, which lets departing travelers deposit their leftover foreign money into various online products such as e-wallets, e-gift cards, or a donation.

It will be located in airports around the world. For instance, people who are about to return from a trip to Turkey could convert their remaining Turkish Lire cash.

I'm trying to make a sign that would explain what the kiosk machine does in the simplest way possible.

I came up with the phrase "Change money into PayPal credit / gift cards" which in my opinion does the job, but some people are telling me that the phrase "Change into" is really not widely used and might be misunderstood.

My question is: What do you think about using "Change into"? It's important to note that only around 50% of users are English speakers.

Comment: I'm seen little shops that buy/sell currency (i.e. convert one currency into another) ... what terminology do they use? "Convert Turkish Lira to …" perhaps?

Answer (score 13):

If, as you say, as many as half your users aren't English speakers, why are you trying to communicate with them using English words?

Why not show the Lira symbol (or better, some Lira banknotes) and arrows to the PayPal logo, pictures of your gift cards (or icons of gifts) etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion about that, but my question was specificaly about the "CHANGE INTO" phrase. What do you think about that? We go with text for this version instead of icons because this is an A/B test where we compare this point exactly. This is the TEXT part of the test :)

Comment: @UriAbramson I think the normal terminology for that is "exchange" (as in "exchange rate"), but if your question is "what English word meaning change/convert is best understood by non-English speakers in Turkey", I'm not sure anyone here is going to be able to help you.

Comment: well.. if you see a sentence "CHANGE YOUR LEFTOVER CURRENCY INTO PayPal Credit" Does it have a bad taste to it? or is it a non issue and explains the meaning?

Comment: @UriAbramson: The best resource I can provide for this sort of a question is [a word frequency level checker](http://language.tiu.ac.jp/flc/) that can help identify any words that aren't common. In your sentence it identifies "currency" and "credit" as being level 3 (academic) level. The others are all level 1 (in the top 1,000 most common words in the English language). That means they're the most likely to be known by non-native speakers. I still think you should use the word "Lira" explicitly instead of "currency" since that word is meaningful for all visitors to Turkey.

Comment: Given that the original poster is looking for a specific English phrase to use, this question would probably get a better answer at [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't think this is a candidate for ELU. There's nothing wrong with "Change your leftover currency into..." The real problem is using English **at all**; there's a reason airport bureaux de change use pictograms.

Answer (score 0):

As Uri specifically asks for a text solution:

I'd go with two words:

*Money Change*